# How to check for keywords in a text file and retrieve multiple segments of text containing the keywords between recurring delimiters

Tags: python, file, parsing, text

I have a list containing some keywords and I am trying to parse a text file containing multiple segments of text between recurring delimiters.  I am trying to check for the presence of the keywords in each segment.  If any of keywords are present, then I would only like to recover those segments (between delimiters) that contain the keywords.

My text file (ParseInput.txt) is as follows:

```
START
cow
sheep
apple
END
//
START
goat
orange
pear
END
//
START
peach
pineapple
watermelon
END
//
```

I have a short python script that looks for the keywords in the text file:

```
from sys import argv

script, ParseInput = argv

import re

animal = ['cow', 'sheep', 'python']

inputFile = open(ParseInput)
parseOutput = re.findall('START(.*?)END', inputFile.read(), re.S)

for result in parseOutput:
  for i in animal:
    if i in result:
      print result
```

Running this script leads to the following output:

```
cow
sheep
apple

cow
sheep
apple
```

The problem is that I only want one instance of the recovered segment.  I think my for/if loops are the problem, but I'm not sure how to fix this and would be grateful for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If **any** of keywords are present, then I would only like to recover
>   those segments (between delimiters) that contain the keywords.

Then do just that! Use the [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) built-in function:

```
for result in parseOutput:
  if any(a in result for a in animal):
      print result
```

Probably worth checking out the [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) built-in while you're at it.

Comment: Should be `print(result)`.

Comment: @DavidMetcalfe well, I can only surmise that the OP is using Python 2 since they have `print` as a statement not a function in their own code...

Comment: I've no doubt that they are using Python 2, but `print()` is compatible with v2.6+.

Comment: @DavidMetcalfe yes, if you `from __future__ import print_function`. It's not really relevant to the question/answer. If anyone wanted *my* advice on the matter, people should just use Python 3 anyway...